# C# - How to Rretrieve Background Color of Window

Tags: c#, background-color

I have searched in this forum and I have not found anything that would help me with the following. Please help if possible. Thank you.

I have set the background of a window to black (or any other color I like). As part of the calculations done by the app, I plot different regions in color on that window. The color of the regions is dynamic and I would like to find and store the starting color of the region before the color change so that I can return to that base color. For example, if the starting background color is black, and the app changes the color to green, I would like to return the color back to the base color black when needed without having to remember that the base color was black.

I tried using

```
private Color backgroundColor = (Color)System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
```

and then later on

```
BackColor = backgroundColor;
```

This does work but the color goes back to white rather than the black I had specified in my preferences.

Can anyone please suggest a solution? Thank you very much for any help you may be bale to provide.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, SystemColors.Window is white by default.  You probably want this:

```
private Color backgroundColor;

private void startPlotting()
{
    backgroundColor = BackColor;
    BackColor = Color.Black;
    // etc..
}

private void restoreWindow()
{ 
    BackColor = backgroundColor;
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I have tried Color backgroundColor = BackColor; but I get an error: object reference is required for non-static field, method, or property and I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: That's why I wrote it in an instance method, not a static method.

Comment: I see. My issue is that this is part of a larger app in which the user can set the background via properties. So the background for all child windows is set via properties and I'd like to retrieve it and store it so I can revert back to it as needed without the need for methods. Is there any way to do it this way? The background color must be strored somewhere so it should be possible to retrieve it. Or, am I wrong here?

Comment: You are talking about code I cannot see.  Yes, I'm sure it is stored somewhere.

Comment: I will see if I can locate where the info on colors set via properties is stored. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color.FromArgb(System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowFrame.ToArgb());
```